# Job hanging when example run on hadoop 0.23.0

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I am trying to add capacity scheduler in hadoop 0.23.0 and trying to run a sample pi, randomwriter program.

All the daemons are up and working fine, but the job is getting hanged and no more output is getting displayed.

I couldnt able to see the logs where they are accumulated. Can anyone please let me know the reason for this hanging of the job, and location where the logs are stored.

```
2012-06-08 18:41:06,118 INFO  mapred.YARNRunner (YARNRunner.java:createApplicationSubmissionContext(355)) - Command to launch container for ApplicationMaster is : $JAVA_HOME/bin/java -Dlog4j.configuration=container-log4j.properties -Dyarn.app.mapreduce.container.log.dir=<LOG_DIR> -Dyarn.app.mapreduce.container.log.filesize=0 -Dhadoop.root.logger=INFO,CLA -Xmx1536m org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster 1><LOG_DIR>/stdout 2><LOG_DIR>/stderr 
2012-06-08 18:41:06,251 INFO  mapred.ResourceMgrDelegate (ResourceMgrDelegate.java:submitApplication(304)) - Submitted application application_1339151256291_0003 to ResourceManager
2012-06-08 18:41:06,355 INFO  mapreduce.Job (Job.java:monitorAndPrintJob(1207)) - Running job: job_1339151256291_0003
2012-06-08 18:41:07,366 INFO  mapreduce.Job (Job.java:monitorAndPrintJob(1227)) -  map 0% reduce 0%
```

Answer (score 1):

I followed the instructions on http://www.thecloudavenue.com/search?q=0.23 and successfully run Hadoop-0.23.4 on a small 3 node cluster.

Check the log files in the

> $HADOOP_HOME/logs

folder for any errors on the master and the slaves.

Check for the following console

> //master:50070/dfshealth.jsp

Check if the number of DataNodes is correct in

> //master:50070/dfsnodelist.jsp?whatNodes=LIVE

Check if the number of  NodeManagers is correctly reported in

> //master:8088/cluster

Also the number of NodeManagers should be correctly specified in

> //master:8088/cluster/nodes

Verify that the output folder with the proper contents has been created through the NameNode Web console

> //master:50070/nn_browsedfscontent.jsp