# Hadoop MapReduce Job Hanging At 0% Mapped

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

This question has already been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10942601/job-hanging-when-example-run-on-hadoop-0-23-0), but there weren't any answers provided so I'm asking again.

I'm trying to run a mapreduce job on hadoop that I've run before without any problems, but as of today each time I try to run it it hangs at 0%.  The job doesn't exit or fail, all the tasks remain pending.  I haven't found anything useful in the logs and everything appears to be normal.  Any suggestions?

```
14/12/10 01:08:01 INFO gcs.GoogleHadoopFileSystemBase: GHFS version: 1.3.0-hadoop1
packageJobJar: [/home/USER/gvcf-mapper.py, /hadoop/tmp/hadoop-unjar6643916888594909673/] []        /tmp/streamjob7416644368405402101.jar tmpDir=null
14/12/10 01:08:05 WARN snappy.LoadSnappy: Snappy native library is available
14/12/10 01:08:05 INFO util.NativeCodeLoader: Loaded the native-hadoop library
14/12/10 01:08:05 INFO snappy.LoadSnappy: Snappy native library loaded
14/12/10 01:08:27 INFO mapred.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 15
14/12/10 01:08:31 INFO streaming.StreamJob: getLocalDirs(): [/hadoop/mapred/local]
14/12/10 01:08:31 INFO streaming.StreamJob: Running job: job_201412092247_0004
14/12/10 01:08:31 INFO streaming.StreamJob: To kill this job, run:
14/12/10 01:08:31 INFO streaming.StreamJob: /home/hadoop/hadoop-install/libexec/../bin/hadoop job  -Dmapred.job.tracker=hadoop-m:9101 -kill job_201412092247_0004
14/12/10 01:08:31 INFO streaming.StreamJob: Tracking URL: http://hadoop-m.c.PROJECT_NAME.internal:50030/jobdetails.jsp?jobid=job_201412092247_0004
14/12/10 01:08:32 INFO streaming.StreamJob:  map 0%  reduce 0%
```

[image: Tracking URL]

Comment: Anything in the logs?

Comment: Nope. Just the XML describing the configuration.